# apt-get install Error

Tags: linux

syslogd during install give following error from the server? How to diagnose this problem

```
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Selecting previously deselected package sysklogd.
(Reading database ... 32541 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking sysklogd (from .../sysklogd_1.5-5ubuntu4_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package klogd.
Unpacking klogd (from .../klogd_1.5-5ubuntu4_amd64.deb) ...

Setting up sysklogd (1.5-5ubuntu4) ...
 * Starting system log daemon...                                         [ OK ] 

Setting up klogd (1.5-5ubuntu4) ...
 * Starting kernel log daemon...                                         [fail]
```

Comment: Is there any relevant information in `syslog` or `messages` or any other log file ?

Comment: This is what i get in /var/log/syslog Nov 18 04:04:06 orb4 kernel: klogd 1.5.0#5ubuntu4, log source = /proc/kmsg started. Nov 18 04:04:06 kernel: Cannot find map file. Nov 18 04:04:06 kernel: No module symbols loaded - kernel modules not enabled

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find any information messages in `/var/log/syslog` then you can start klogd in debug mode. In this mode it will print lots of information to stderr so you should be able to find out what's the problem from that.

```
/sbin/klogd -d
```